# Cannot Test MockMultipartFile with Spring Boot Test - No serializer found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to mock the upload of an image to a controller endpoint which is expecting a DTO containing a MultipartFile input along with several plain text fields. But I can't seem to mock a MultipartFile to send:

Here is my **test:**

```
 @Test
  public void saveAnEntryWhenPOSTNewUserWithAPicture() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile multiPFImage = new MockMultipartFile("contactImgUpload", "abcpic.png",
            "text/plain", "Generate bytes to simulate a picture".getBytes());
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/newContact")
            .file(multiPFImage)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .param("userId", "12345")
            .param("name", "Picture Uploader User"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Picture Uploader User")))
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Replace with image title")));
  }
```

The **controller** method we are testing:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/newContact")
  public @ResponseBody ContactDTO createNewContact(@ModelAttribute ContactDTO newContact) {

   //converts newContact to DAO and persists to DB

   return newContact
}
```

The **DTO** for conversion:

```
public class ContactDTO implements Serializable {

  private BigInteger userId;
  private BigInteger contactId; //automatically generated on persistence
  private String name;
  private MultipartFile contactImgUpload;
}
```

When I run the test, it fails, and I get this message:

> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP
>   message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class
>   java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create
>   BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer
>   found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties
>   discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain:
>   app.models.dto.ContactDTO["contactImgUpload"]->org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile["inputStream"])

I've seen several other instances of this question, but most don't have answers, or aren't quite the same. Any ideas on how to test a  MockMultipartFile that needs to bind to the DTO?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this :

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;

@Before
public void before() {
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
}
```